# Group itemize text by placing } in LyX

Tags: lists, lyx

Is it possible in Lyx to group itemize text with this symbol } ?
In order to understand what i want to do , i attach a screenshot :

[image: List]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not in LyX directly but using the LaTeX functionality available from within LyX:

Go to `Document | Settings | Latex Preamble`

and add

```
\usepackage{multirow,bigdelim}
```

Then, go to `Insert | TeX Code` and in the box that comes up, enter

```
\begin{tabular}{ll} 
Text 1 & \rdelim\}{3}{1mm}[\hspace{2mm} My texts]  \\ 
Text 2 \\ 
Text 3 \\ 
\end{tabular}
```

where the 3 in `\rdelim\}{3}` has to correspond to the number of text items you want to enter, and the 2 in `\hspace{2mm}` determines the distance of the text from the brace to its right.

[image]

Does that help?

Comment: vaettchen thank you so much :D
I did it.. it was exactly what i wanted ;)