# How can I create a brace spanning multiple lines on the right side of an itemized list?

Tags: lists

I have an itemized list:

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item Lorem
    \item Ipsum
    \item Sit
    \item Dolor
    \item Amet
\end{itemize}
```

I want to create an accolade on the right side of 'Lorem' and 'Ipsum', and add a bit of text at the point of the accolade. The level of this text should be between the first and the second line. How can I get this done?

[image: example]

Comment: This one might be a duplicate of either **[Group itemize text by placing } in LyX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/75514/4778)** or **[Large braces over several items in an itemize with text by the brace](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12391/4778)** (see second answer).

Comment: Not sure about the context because you do not provide a minimum working example. Just in case you hadn't realised this, your brace may not look very pretty if there's a page break between the _Lorem_ and _Ipsum._

Comment: Thank you, but http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/75514/4778 doesn't seem to work with itemized lists. http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12391/4778 works, but doesn't notice where the last line is, and will mangle up the accolade a bit: [see here](http://i.imgur.com/ntAfXZh.png)

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: what else should I provide?

Comment: @Exeleration-G Not sure. Why do you need it? Is there another way you can draw the reader's attention that the two items are related? Perhaps you can have a top-level item with a short sentence and then an itemized list with _Lorem_ and _Ipsum?_

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: I need this because it's part of a summary I'm writing for myself. I'm pretty new to LaTeX, so right now, I'm just focusing on getting everything done in LaTeX what I used to be able to do in LibreOffice. But the suggestion you made is useful.

Comment: @Exeleration-G Graag gedaan.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A little more generality is needed. The OP's example works nicely because 'Lorem' and 'Ipsum' have about the same width. But if the Ipsum line is longer, then this is the output:

[image: Original output]

Taking a cue from [Large braces over several items in an itemize with text by the brace](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12391/4778), we can write the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}% for cropping
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calc}
\newcommand{\ntikzmark}[2]{#2\thinspace\tikz[overlay,remember picture,baseline=(#1.base)]{\node[inner sep=0pt] (#1) {};}}

\newcommand{\makebrace}[3]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
        \draw [decoration={brace,amplitude=0.5em},decorate]
        let \p1=(#1), \p2=(#2) in
        ({max(\x1,\x2)}, {\y1+0.8em}) -- node[right=0.6em] {#3} ({max(\x1,\x2)}, {\y2});
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item \ntikzmark{L}{Very Long Lorem}
    \item \ntikzmark{O}{Long Ipsum}
    \item \ntikzmark{X}{Sit}
    \item \ntikzmark{Y}{Dolor}
    \item Amet
\end{itemize}
\makebrace{L}{O}{Bla bla bla.}
\makebrace{X}{Y}{More bla bla bla.}

\end{document}
```

which yields:

[image: Corrected output]

And changing 'Lorem' to 'Very Long Lorem' yields:

[image: Alternate corrected output]

It occurred to me that you might more than one brace. I altered the code to accommodate that possibility. The output in this case looks like this:

[image: Alternate output]

The trick is to find the longest line, and base the drawing of the brace on that. There may be an easier way, and I would like to see it...

#

At the risk of seeming tedious, I have simplified the interface a bit and made possible a formatting option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calc}

\newcounter{itemnum}

\newcommand{\nt}[2][0pt]{%
    \stepcounter{itemnum}%
    \if###2##%
    \else
        #2%
        \thinspace
    \fi
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture,baseline=(\theitemnum.base),xshift=#1]\node (\theitemnum){};%
}

\newcommand{\makebrace}[4][0pt]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
        \draw [decoration={brace,amplitude=0.5em},decorate]
        let \p1=(#2), \p2=(#3) in
        ({max(\x1+#1,\x2+#1)}, {\y1+1.75ex}) -- 
            node[right=0.6em] {#4} ({max(\x1+#1,\x2+#1)}, {\y2-0.5ex});
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\newenvironment{braceitems}{%
    \begin{enumerate}
}{%
    \end{enumerate}
    \setcounter{itemnum}{0}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{braceitems}
    \item \nt{Very Long Lorem}
    \item \nt{Long Ipsum}
    \item \nt{Sit}
    \item \nt{Dolor}
    \item \nt{Amet}
\end{braceitems}
\makebrace{1}{2}{Bla bla bla.}
\makebrace{2}{5}{More bla bla bla.}
\makebrace{4}{5}{A note.}

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: New output]

which is not exactly what is wanted. So we use the optional argument to move the brace, `\makebrace[15pt]{2}{5}{More bla bla bla.}` to get this:

[image: Better new output]

**Explanation:** A new counter `itemnum` keeps track of the items in the list. Use the numbers of the items in `\makebrace` to determine how the brace is drawn. An optional argument to `\makebrace` will move the brace.

As it happens, this suggested an interesting solution to a problem in recipe formatting, which is why I seem fixated on the solution.

---

I have altered the code slightly. I discovered that this, for example, `\item \nt{Very Long Lorem\\and more}` would produce this:

[image: Two line \item bad outout]

Again, probably not what is wanted. I changed the code for `\nt` to allow for an empty argument, which simple creates an anchor for the drawing of the brace: `\item Very Long Lorem\nt{}\\and more`, which produces this:

[image: Two line \item with better output]

Comment: Taking a cue from ...

Comment: Had to change the 'correct' answer to this one

Answer (score 8):

## Remarks

Using the almighty TikZ and it `decorations.pathreplacing` library to place the `brace` decoration.

## Implementation

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}% for cropping
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[2]{\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base)]{\node[inner sep=0pt] (#1) {#2};}}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \tikzmark{L}{Lorem}
    \item \tikzmark{I}{Ipsum}
    \item Sit
    \item Dolor
    \item Amet
\end{itemize}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \draw[decorate,decoration={brace}] (L.north east) -- node[right] {Bla bla bla} (L.north east |- I.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Output

> [image]