# Braces in enumerate environment to span two or more lines

Tags: enumerate, braces, tikzmark

I was attempting to get a brace to show up on lines 2 and 3 in an enumerate environment.  The solution given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/138968/how-can-i-create-a-brace-spanning-multiple-lines-on-the-right-side-of-an-itemize) is used in the first enumerate environment, but the brace did not look as appealing as the brace in the second solution.

Is there a way to get the thick brace given in the second enumerate environment to display in the first enumerate environment?

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}% for cropping
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[2]{\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base)]{\node[inner sep=0pt] (#1) {#2};}}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item First item
    \item \tikzmark{L}{Second is a much longer item}
    \item \tikzmark{I}{Third item}
    \item Fourth item
    \item Fifth item
\end{enumerate}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \draw[decorate,decoration={brace}] (L.north east) -- node[right] {Noise} (L.north east |- I.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}

$\left.\begin{minipage}{5.5cm}
\begin{enumerate}
\item First item
\item Second is a much longer item
\item Third item
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}\right\rbrace$ Some comment

\end{document}
```

Comment: The first brace is drawn using `tikz` so you can change the line width with options `ultra thick`, or `thick`, or specify `line width=2pt`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the first brace is drawn using `tikz` you can apply options to the `\draw` to control the line width. Below I used `line width=1.25pt, draw=red`:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}% for cropping
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[2]{\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base)]{\node[inner sep=0pt] (#1) {#2};}}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item First item
    \item \tikzmark{L}{Second is a much longer item}
    \item \tikzmark{I}{Third item}
    \item Fourth item
    \item Fifth item
\end{enumerate}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \draw[decorate,decoration={brace}, line width=1.25pt, draw=red] (L.north east) -- node[right] {Noise} (L.north east |- I.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}

$\left.\begin{minipage}{5.5cm}
\begin{enumerate}
\item First item
\item Second is a much longer item
\item Third item
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}\right\rbrace$ Some comment

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution.  Is it possible to add the same `\rbrace` to the first example?  I tried placing `\rbrace` in the `\draw[decorate,decoration={$\rbrace$},` but that did not work.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Joe: I don't think you can simply use `decoration={$\rbrace$}`. What exactly is the output that you are trying to achieve? it is much easier to customize the brace options than it is to apply the same technique as was done to the `minipage` to a _few_ of the list items.  I think it would require splitting up the list.